# populating a dataframe column in pandas with another dataframe's column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm generating a list of conference names from the database and trying to populate them into a column in another dataframe. For some reason it's not working and returning NaN. Can anyone help explain why it's doing that? Why the last line isn't doing what it's supposed to?

```
df_conf = pd.read_sql("select distinct Conference from publications where year>=1991 and length(conference)>1 order by conference", db)

df_if= pd.DataFrame(index=df_conf['Conference'], columns=['Conference','IF1994','IF1995'])


df_if['Conference'] = df_conf['Conference']
```

Comment: It's because the indices don't align, if the 2 df's are the same length you could do `df_if['Conference'] = df_conf['Conference'].values` to assign the np array values

Comment: That solved it. They should have aligned though, cause if you notice the index of `df_if` is `df_conf['Conference']`

Comment: All you did was set the index to the str values, that doesn't mean the index of `df_conf` matches `df_if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get all `NaN` values is because the index values are not aligned.

To assign the values as just values you can do this:

```
df_if['Conference'] = df_conf['Conference'].values
```

What you did was create `df_if` with an index set to `df_conf['conference']` but that doesn't mean that the index of `df_if` and `df_conf` match.